# Not able to run shell script over ssh using php

Tags: php, shell, ssh

I'm trying to run a shell script over ssh using php. I'm been able to achieve running a simple command but not a shell script and I've tried pretty much everything I could find over the google.

Here's the script:

```
<?php
 use SSH2;
 echo shell_exec("whoami");
 ?>
```

Same script passing the shell script won't run:

```
?php
use SSH2;
echo shell_exec("bash awsserver.sh");
?>
```

Comment: Try shell_exec("whoami  2>&1");

Comment: @BrettGregson Passing a simple command is working like whoami , pwd, ls, echo but not when I try to run a script through command like "bash awsserver.sh"

Comment: Re: `use SSH2;`. That, in and of itself, isn't sufficient to make PHP run commands through SSH...

Comment: @neubert Do you know how can I achieve the same?

Comment: Take a look at http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/2.0/examples.html

Comment: @neubert This was the first thing that I tried, I was using this on Apache+php-fpm. I can this try again and let you know if it worked. Phpseclib was also just able to run normal commands and not the bash script (even though it is also just a command "bash script.sh")

Comment: @Axel - I'd need more info to diagnose the `bash script.sh` problem. Maybe SSH logs or something. In lieu of those I'd say try enabling PTY mode. eg. `$ssh->enablyPTY()`.